# Why my program of Matrix multiplication using C doesn't work?

Tags: c, matrix

I wrote a program to calculate the **matrix multiplication**.I takes user input to define the size of the array and the elements contained.(My knowledge on programming should be considered as a beginner).When I execute the program it prints a null array. When I tested the code line by line. I found out that the program works correctly till the calculation of the matrix.(Taking user input and calling the function).
I couldn't find the source of the problem. I have included part of the code which contains the multiplication function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100
void matrix_mul(int, int, int, int, int [MAX][MAX], int [MAX][MAX]);

int main()
{

int mat_1[MAX][MAX] ,mat_2[MAX][MAX];
int row1, row2, column1, column2;

printf("Input number of rows for the first matrix:  ");
scanf("%d", &row1);
printf("Input number of columns for the first matrix:  ");
scanf("%d", &column1);

printf("Input number of rows for the second matrix:  ");
scanf("%d", &row2);
printf("Input number of columns for the second matrix:  ");
scanf("%d", &column2);

if(column1 != row2 || column2 != row1)
{
    printf("Incompatible matrices. Try Again! ");
    return 0;
}

printf("Enter elements for matrix 1 of order %d x %d\n", row1, column1);

for(int i=0; i<row1; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<column1; j++)
        scanf("%d", &mat_1[i][j]);
}

printf("\n\nEnter elements for matrix 1 of order %d x %d\n", row2, column2);

for(int i=0; i<row2; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<column2; j++)
        scanf("%d", &mat_2[i][j]);
}
 matrix_mul(row1, row2, column1, column2, mat_1, mat_2);

}

// for testing r1 = 3 c1 =2 r2 =2 c2 =3
void matrix_mul(int row1, int row2, int column1, int column2, int ar1[MAX][MAX], int ar2[MAX][MAX])
{

    int arr [MAX][MAX]; 

    for(int i=0 ; i<row1; i++)
    {

        for(int j=0; j<column2; j++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for(int k=0; k<column1; k++)
                sum += ar1[row1][k] * ar2[column1][row1];
            printf("%d", sum);
            arr[row1][column2] = sum;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<row1; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<column2; j++)
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up your loop values with your boundaries. Here's the corrected versions of the relevant lines:

```
            sum += ar1[i][k] * ar2[k][j];
```

```
        arr[i][j] = sum;
```

You're seeing `88888` instead of `8` because you left a debugging statement in:

```
printf("%d", sum);
```

Remove that and you'll only see the correct output.

Comment: for matrices of 2x2 (both containing values of only 2). It prints 88888 8
8 8

Comment: @NisanAbeywickrama That seems unlikely. Can you post a full program that will cause that, rather than just a function?

Comment: @NisanAbeywickrama Okay, that's because you had an extra `printf` that you didn't post the first time. Answer updated regarding it. Also, please don't "fix" the code in the question from the answer, as it makes the answer no longer make sense.